# Windows: Running an AutoIt script to launch a GUI app - on a server, when no one is logged in

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, scheduled-task, autoit

I want to run an AutoIt script every day at 1:00 AM on a Windows 2003 Server Standard Edition. Since this is a server, obviously there is rarely someone sitting there logged in at the console, so the procedure needs to account for this.

The AutoIt script in question launches and sends keypresses to a GUI app, so the process needs to include creating some sort of session for the user running the schedule task.

Is there a way to do this?

- I can't just use scheduled tasks run the AutoIt script when no one is logged in - if I do, it fails to launch at all.
- I thought that I might be able to create an RDP session and run the scheduled task as that user, inside that session, but I haven't found a way to create an RDP session without launching mstsc.exe -- which is itself a GUI app, and I have the same problem again.

Comment: Wow, I'd contact the developer/company responsible for the app and demand a command-line compatible version asap ^^

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if srvany from Microsoft allows to run GUI apps as a service, but [AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/) does. You could then use Windows Scheduled Tasks or anything else to make sure your script runs at the desired time.

Answer (score 0):

[**How to use Schtasks.exe to Schedule Tasks in Windows Server 2003**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596)

And for **AutoIt** -- [**Task Scheduler UDF**](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=83355) (User Defined Function).
Has a AutoIt function for the purpose.

You will find more such useful functions at the [AutoItScript Wiki UDF page](http://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/UDF).

> Listing of libraries of user defined functions
>   These libraries have been written to allow easy integratation into your own script and therefore are very valuable resources for any programmer.

Answer (score 0):

you can launch Remote Desktop from the command line. use AutoIt on a machine to RemoteDesktop into your target server.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [AutoLogon](https://live.sysinternals.com/files/AutoLogon.zip) from Microsoft.  This will logon to the server after boot.  Then a Scheduled task can be set to run after logon.

To ensure that it runs regularly you could have the machine reboot at a set time each day, once again initiating the Autologon and logon scheduled task(s).